# I want to install a package with "composer require laravelista/comments" but it appears an error

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-8

Using version ^3.6 for laravelista/comments
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v8.14.0
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- laravelista/comments 3.6.0 requires illuminate/queue ^5.6|^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/queue[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, 7.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.19, v6.18.2, v6.18.20, v6.18.21, v6.18.22, v6.18.23, v6.18.24, v6.18.25, v6.18.26, v6.18.27, v6.18.28, v6.18.29, v6.18.3, v6.18.30, v6.18.31, v6.18.32, v6.18.33, v6.18.34, v6.18.35, v6.18.36, v6.18.37, v6.18.38, v6.18.39, v6.18.4, v6.18.40, v6.18.41, v6.18.42, v6.18.43, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.19.0, v6.19.1, v6.2.0, v6.20.0, v6.20.1, v6.20.2, v6.20.3, v6.20.4, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.21.0, v7.22.0, v7.22.1, v7.22.2, v7.22.3, v7.22.4, v7.23.0, v7.23.1, v7.23.2, v7.24.0, v7.25.0, v7.26.0, v7.26.1, v7.27.0, v7.28.0, v7.28.1, v7.28.2, v7.28.3, v7.28.4, v7.29.0, v7.29.1, v7.29.2, v7.29.3, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
- laravelista/comments 3.6.1 requires illuminate/queue ^5.6|^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/queue[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, 7.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.19, v6.18.2, v6.18.20, v6.18.21, v6.18.22, v6.18.23, v6.18.24, v6.18.25, v6.18.26, v6.18.27, v6.18.28, v6.18.29, v6.18.3, v6.18.30, v6.18.31, v6.18.32, v6.18.33, v6.18.34, v6.18.35, v6.18.36, v6.18.37, v6.18.38, v6.18.39, v6.18.4, v6.18.40, v6.18.41, v6.18.42, v6.18.43, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.19.0, v6.19.1, v6.2.0, v6.20.0, v6.20.1, v6.20.2, v6.20.3, v6.20.4, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.21.0, v7.22.0, v7.22.1, v7.22.2, v7.22.3, v7.22.4, v7.23.0, v7.23.1, v7.23.2, v7.24.0, v7.25.0, v7.26.0, v7.26.1, v7.27.0, v7.28.0, v7.28.1, v7.28.2, v7.28.3, v7.28.4, v7.29.0, v7.29.1, v7.29.2, v7.29.3, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
- don't install illuminate/queue 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue 6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue 7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.36|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.10.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.11.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.12.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.13.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.13.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.14.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.15.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.15.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.16.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.17.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.17.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.10|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.11|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.12|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.13|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.14|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.15|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.16|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.17|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.18|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.19|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.20|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.21|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.22|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.23|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.24|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.25|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.26|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.27|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.28|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.29|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.3|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.30|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.31|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.32|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.33|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.34|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.35|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.36|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.37|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.38|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.39|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.4|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.40|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.41|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.42|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.43|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.5|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.6|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.7|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.8|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.18.9|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.19.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.19.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.20.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.20.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.20.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.20.3|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.20.4|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.4.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.5.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v6.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.0.5|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.0.6|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.0.7|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.0.8|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.1.3|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.10.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.10.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.10.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.10.3|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.11.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.12.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.13.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.14.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.14.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.15.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.16.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.16.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.17.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.17.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.17.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.18.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.19.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.19.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.2.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.2.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.20.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.21.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.22.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.22.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.22.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.22.3|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.22.4|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.23.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.23.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.23.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.24.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.25.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.26.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.26.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.27.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.28.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.28.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.28.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.28.3|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.28.4|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.29.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.29.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.29.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.29.3|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.5.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.8.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.9.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.9.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- don't install illuminate/queue v7.9.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v8.14.0, required as ^8.12) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.14.0].
- Installation request for laravelista/comments ^3.6 -> satisfiable by laravelista/comments[3.6.0, 3.6.1].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Comment: As the text indicates: the package you want to install can only work with laravel 5.6, 6 or 7. But you are using laravel 8. So that's a problem. Either use laravel 7, our contact the package developer and see if there are plans to upgrade the package to with with L8, or help the developer by editing the package yourself and create a pull request or choose another package with the same functions that does work with L8.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using btw?

Comment: Please share more details, like the current packages listed in your `composer.json`  and your debugging attempts. Also, please share which parts of that composer output are unclear to you

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that package at that version (3.6) does not support Laravel 8. You would have to go up to version >= 4.0.0 for Laravel 8 support.

This will bump the PHP requirement though, as this package in 4.0.0 requires PHP >= 7.4 and Laravel 8 only requires PHP >= 7.3.